# Injecting a complete module in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject.web.mvc

I am developing a multi-tenant application based on ASP.Net MVC. Depending on the user setup, the site needs to redirect to a separate module/area for that user. Each area has uses some common services, however the site's look and feel and navigation are completely different for each area/ module. Models are also overridden from a base library and we need separate teams to develop the modules (which includes controllers, views and models).

We are considering dependency injection tools such as Unity or Ninject for the same. Question is how do we inject complete module/area inside a main web site. Controllers and Models part is well understood. What is not clear is how to develop Views so that correct views are searched and used.

**UPDATE**
We need to develop this application with different teams. Each team will develop a module per sub-site/ area. There is a business layer which provides common services, framework and workflows. MVC is primarily a presentation layer. Each team develops a sub-site per customer using specific branding for that customer. As we add more customers, we need to add more sites. We could have used themes etc. However, the customers have different screens and different set of fields per screen. All these fields capture similar data however, the end users are in different roles to capture the data. E.g. The front office person captures varying no. of fields per customer and back end person completes the remainder. Similarly there could be more than one users facing customer's customers (visitors). There is a common component which is used for managing the visitors flow, front end desks in each office session etc. Question is how do we independently develop the MVC sub-sites and bring them under a common site using dependency injection. Specially the views. Is deployment script the only option?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand.

Your goal is to use Dependency Injection with something like Ninject so that you can inject different implementations based on the Controller in a particular area being used in your application?

If this is the case, you can setup NinjectModules that bind certain implementations of a particular service defined by your interface or abstract class through the Ninject Named attribute, which you can place on your Controller Constructors.

For example, you might have a general Search Controller that is open to the public in an area such  as

> http://example.com/**users**/home/search

Using Ninject Named Attribute you could inject an implementation of a ISearchService which is consumed by that controller, which may offer a limited amount of functionality for public users to search properties on,

however in another area of the site, such as admin or users who post their own properties on the site may get more access through the search functionality

> http://example.com/**tenants**/home/search

This HomeController can have a different injected implementation of the ISearchService which is passed through its constructor.

Just ensure to load all your NinjectModules in Global.asax

This can be found under the [Ninject Contextual Bindings documentation here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

I'm going on very little information from what you've given me here, you may get better answers if you provide a little more context / code examples of the issue you are facing with your architectural design considerations.